# Phone is overheating in less than 10 minutes of usage

Tags: overheating

I have Lava Iris 405+ running on Jelly Bean. It overheats in less than 10 minutes of Twitter, WhatsApp use. Even tethering overheats CPU.

How to prevent/fix this, or identify which causes the overheat?

Comment: Are you sure it's the CPU? Check if background apps are launching malicious services in the background eating a lot of CPU, what makes it run at max clock rate all the time.

Comment: If it's literally overheating, take a look at the battery as well.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, find out what is causing the heating issues, the **CPU** or the **battery**.

Download [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en) from the Play Store and open it up.

In the first tab, ie `SOC`, check the clock speeds of each core and compare them with your stock clock speed (1.3GHz) and check `CPU Load`.

If the cores constantly run at 1.3GHz, then as GiantTree said, you have got some background apps that are causing the heating. Go over to `Settings -> Apps -> Running` to find the apps.

If not, check the `Temperature` in the `Battery` tab. Anything above 40 C is harmful. This could be caused by a faulty battery. Try replacing it.
Either way, use during charging is not recommended.